# How can I read python dictionaries in R as dataframe or matrix?

Tags: python, r, dictionary

I have `Counter` output which are counts of occurrences in a `list`, which I saved as `dictionary` format. For instance I have something like this:

```
{'apple':4, 'orange':5, 'grape':6 ....}
```

I want to read this in R so that I can manipulate and index the data,

```
apple 4
orange 5
grape 6
```

in `matrix` or `dataframe`. How can I do this? I saved the dictionary as `txt` format.

Comment: I don't think python dictionary output as straight text is immediately a standard that non-python languages import. Though it'd be possible to write a parser that does this, I'd suggest instead you write the data (from python) in a format that is more prevalent, such as json, xml, or yaml, either with pros/cons; all of them have well-functioning import/export in both languages. (There are others, I'm confident.)

Comment: @r2evans so do you mean i should save the dictionary as json format, and then import from R?

Comment: Yes. Python: `json.dumps({'apple':4, 'orange':5, 'grape':6})` will output `'{"orange": 5, "grape": 6, "apple": 4}'`. R: `jsonlite::fromJSON(txt='{"orange": 5, "grape": 6, "apple": 4}')` gives you a named list.

Comment: @r2evans seems like I can save the json output as .json and then read it in R with jsonlie:::fromJSON command in R? I saved the output as txt after using json.dumps in python.

Comment: Yes. `fromJSON` also accepts a filename instead of `txt`, so `fromJSON(filename)` works as desired.

Comment: @r2evans got it, Thanks!!